# Speakker Hide Social Media Buttons

Tags: html5-audio, projekktor

I have been looking for a media player for a project that I am working on and I stumbled upon Speakker (http://www.speakker.com/) today.  Speakker seems to offer exactly what I am looking for, however, there are a couple of buttons on the interface that I just can not have (see below in red).

[image: Player]

Has anyone else used this player before, and if so, how can I get rid of these buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable them by altering the "plugin_share" config-object. You need to set the value for each entry to "false" like:

```
$projekktor('.speakker dark', {
    plugin_share: {
        links: {
        'download': false
        'lastfm': false,
        'wikipedia': false,
        'admin': false          
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not _hide_ the buttons, it only disables their functionality.  Is there no way to completely remove them from the view?